# How to $.extend objects with sub-objects in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, merge

I know i can use `$.extend({}, x);` to merge the contents of two or more objects together into the first object, but my answer is, and the sub-objects? They will only be overwritten? I can't merge then?

I have this:

```
var settings = $.extend({
    modal: {
        title: "Atention",
        type: "text",
        width: "small"
    },
    ajax: {
        type: "normal",
        trigger: "",
        url: ""
    }
}, {
    modal: {
        title: "Registrar",
        type: "register"
    },
    ajax: {
        trigger: ".bumbum",
        url: "modal/lets/go"
    }
});
```

This jQuery function will return this:

```
var setting = {
    modal: {
        title: "Registrar",
        type: "register"
    },
    ajax: {
        trigger: ".bumbum",
        url: "modal/lets/go"
    }
};
```

And unfortunately I need it:

```
var setting = {
    ajax: {
        type: "normal",
        trigger: ".bumbum",
        url: "modal/lets/go"
    },
    modal: {
        title: "Registrar",
        type: "register",
        width: "small"
    }
};
```

Any idea? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For deep nesting try, `$.extend(true, {}, x);`. For deep nesting the format is:

[`jQuery.extend( [ deep ], target, object1 [, objectN ] )`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/#jQuery-extend-target-object1-objectN);

Comment: There. I thought you wouldn't move the `true`. :D

Comment: Man, so simple... I just look into the first function into the docs `jQuery.extend( target [, object1 ] [, objectN ] )`, a new lesson has been learned. Read the docs until the end... haha